# vi command returns error format data?

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I'm using python 2.7 and **paramiko** library. client app running on window sends ssh commands to server app running on linux.
 when I send **vi** command, I get the response
`<-[0m<-[24;2H<-[K<-[24;1H<-[1m~<-[0m<-[25;2H....`
 I don't know what these characters mean and how I process it. I'm struggling for hours, please help me.

Comment: vi command is an interactive file editor... if you run it from a python script it would get stuck. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @cad: Thanks for your quick response. I'm not using python script. I'm trying to edit a file from a remote computer. What I'm trying to do is when client sends vi command to server, server will send file content to client so that client can display the content, and allow users to edit the content. When done editting, client will send edited content back to server to save it.

Comment: @BùiTrịnhMinhTuấn You know the scenario better than me :) Wouldn't make more logic to use local vim to access file in server using samba or sftp mounted unit or something similar?

Comment: @cad: It's easier to do that, but I'm building a system to do it myself; not only the vi command but every ssh commands

Comment: @High Performance Mark:Yes, that's the case. I got the file content following those characters, and I want to know what's the characters mean to proces the data correctly.I want to know what the characters mean to proces the data correctly.

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck... If putty is capable of doing it, you should be able too.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: that's exactly what I need, thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing my SO activity this week, saw this opportunity to whore for rep:

Those look like ANSI/VT100 terminal control codes, which suggests that something which thinks it is attached to a terminal is sending them but they are being received by something which doesn't know what to do with them.

Now you can Google for 'VT100 control codes' and learn what you want.